# jquery .ajax() call has status 0, but the responseText is exactly right

Tags: jquery, ajax

Has anyone ever seen this?  I go into the error handler with status 0, but the responseText is exactly what I wanted to see.

Somehow this is happening only from some PCs generally only requests from Google Earth.  I had to do an alert() on the .failure arguments to see the status code and responseText.

```
$.ajax({
        url: myServletUrl
        data: {id: theId}
        }
).success(function(result){
                            alert(result);//normally happens
                           }
).failure(function(xhr){
                            alert(xhr.status +" - " xhr.responseText);
                            //I get "0 - xxxxx" where xxxx is a json string.
                       }
);
```

Edit, same issue seen here:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/earth-issues/issues/1332

Comment: Can you post your code and a sample response please?

Comment: I've added some code, but it's not necessary.  Anyone vaguely familiar with jquery ajax would know what this looks like.

Comment: I'm very familiar with `jQuery.ajax`, however without an actual code snippet the vaguely worded question will probably downvoted and closed. Is this a code snippet or your actual code snippet?

Comment: While your question is a general "anyone seen this" it will still get close-voted as: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  Please have a read of this [mcve]

Comment: This is still happening for me at random in GE 7.0.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the most elegant solution we could come up with.  It requires refactoring your success function into a named function, instead of something anonymous.

```
$.ajax({
        url: myServletUrl
        data: {id: theId}
        }
).success(function(result){
                            successFunction(result);//normally happens
                           }
).failure(function(xhr, statusText){
                            if(xhr.status===0 && xhr.responseText){
                                 //GE bug, really success.
                                 successFunction(xhr.responseText);
                            }else{ 
                                 alert("FAILURE - "+ statusText);

                            }
                       }
);
```